# Use Angular Ui-router without any views or templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I've used UI router in the past in single page applications and found it prefect for loading new views and syncing them with the URL. However, I now have a normal multi-page ecommerce site which uses Angular a lot on various pages. Including te search results page.

I need to use ui-router only on this page to do ajax paging. Basically the content is already loaded onto the page and I have an ng-repeat for the results. It's a very simple set up.

What I want to do is change the state/url when the user hits the next/previous buttons and watch the stateParams to look for the new page number, then manually reload the new results and re-bind the ng-repeat to show the new results. Obviously I could load new search results without using ui-router at all but I want the back button to work so that you can go back through the pages.

Now, as far as I can see none of this requires any ui-view tags, or templates or controllers. I simply want to update the URL when a button is clicked and watch for changes. Is this possible with UI-router and if it is then what routes (if any) do I put into $stateProvider config?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything at all? and how would you use ui-router without a ui-view?

Comment: Routers and `view` tag go hand in hand...hard to use one without the other

Comment: As far as I understand, when you call something like $state.go(), the router changes it's internal state, updates the URL, updates the $stateParams etc. and also loads a template into your UI-view. My hope is that I can use it to do the first few things so I don't have to worry about URLs/history but I have no need to load a new template when the state changes, all I want to do is trigger an update of some data.

Comment: If the goal is just to change the URL, all you need is the $location service. No need for a router.

Comment: I have always used UI-router because it did everything I needed it to do. I will look into just using $location to handle the javascript history when paging through results. I also need to get the back button working when opening Angular UI modals so may have to use UI-router anyway.